# Android google map error

Tags: android, google-maps

In my project eclispe does not *debug* any *error* ! but when run it's *force to stop*

this is my ***logcat*** any idea !!!

```
07-08 11:20:41.494: WARN/dalvikvm(735): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.remwebdevelopment.maptest/com.remwebdevelopment.maptest.MapTest}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.remwebdevelopment.maptest.MapTest in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.remwebdevelopment.maptest-2.apk]
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.remwebdevelopment.maptest.MapTest in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.remwebdevelopment.maptest-2.apk]
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
07-08 11:20:41.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(735):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have refer this ? http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Answer (score 1):

You have either changed your AndroidManifest.xml to update the application package name without changing the `<activity>` definition for `com.remwebdevelopment.maptest.MapTest` or you did not define an `<activity>` entry for `com.remwebdevelopment.maptest.MapTest` in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thank, but Why when i run it again ( after changing ) it shows only grid line no map n in log cat it show IO Exception !

Comment: That's a separate problem: would need to put the IOException into a question of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution (similar to other people's answers) was to use the Manifest editor in eclipse. I just removed the "uses library" entry in the application tab and added it again. It put the node at the bottom of the tree (just before the application tag is closed) and it works now. It used to exist half way up the tree of nodes.

**UPDATE**

I also found later that I needed to update my project according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7971104/516286) post by running the command `android update project -p .`

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me after an ADT/SDK upgrade. Good grief.

Answer (score 0):

Had this sort of problem today after upgrading to latest ADT/SDK. Also for me the exception was

```
Unable to instantiate activity
```

Took me quite a while. Checked that i used google-apis (for maps), uses-library, cleaned the project etc.

Deleting the .project and adding a fresh one (create new android project) finally solved it.