# Project.properties file instead of default.properties file

Tags: android, adt

I stumbled across something I can't figure out myself.

I have an android project with a reference to a library project. Now, the weird thing is that it seems like my default.properties file is no longer needed. Android creates a project.properties file. So my questions is: what is the difference between the two? Isn't a project.properties file standard java and default.properties android specific? What do they do exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you've got an issue where (some of) your project files have become obsolete after an update to a newer Android SDK.

Run this command in your project directory (you'll need to have ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools in your path):

```
android update project -p .
```

It will output something similar to (As of SDK 15):

- Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
- Updated local.properties
- No project name specified, using Activity name 'MainActivity'. If you wish to change it, edit the first line of    build.xml.
- Added file ./build.xml
- Updated file ./proguard.cfg

My guess is that the Android team decided to become more standardized and to do away with their own deviations from standards.

Comment: This change was made in ADT 14.0. See the discussion at http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14 (under the heading "Project setup").